# I need to echo multiplication with decimals in bash

Tags: bash, decimal, echo

I am trying to multiply decimals and echo them

Here is what I have so far ...

```
#!/bin/bash

gbspace=1
limitUsers=2
limitInstances=2

echo $(($gbspace*0.5)) GB Webspace
echo limitUsers:$(($limitUsers*5))
echo limitUsers:$(($limitUsers*5)), limitInstances:$(($limitInstances)) \| Hi
```

and this is what I get ...

```
root@home /home/work # bash run
run: line 7: 1*0.5: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".5")
limitUsers:10
limitUsers:10, limitInstances:2 | Hi
```

Comment: Bash does only integer arithmetic. You can either modify the logic to use integer arithmetic, or else use an external program to do your arithmetic.

Comment: BTW, instead of multiplying by `0.5`, why don't you divide by `2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bc` which is pre-installed on most systems, with the -l flag to enable floating-point arithmetic:

```
echo $(echo "$gbspace*0.5" | bc -l) "GB Webspace"
```

Note that you have to be careful with the quoting, and you have to pipe the expression you want to compute to `bc` with the `echo` command.

Comment: Note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the reference to questions which *"have already been asked and answered many times before"*.

Comment: Fabien's answer was exactly what I needed. I did see those other threads beforehand but didn't understand how I could implement it correctly. Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: will do. Thanks for the pointer and the reminder!